CSS display flex space between not working
Just to start, I have to admit I'm pretty amateur to flexbox and CSS. So, sorry for any naive mistakes.
I have the following code:


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #333;
  /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background: white;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  gap: 16px;
}

.icon-item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.info-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.header-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.icon {
  color: royalblue;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: lavender;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
  background: royalblue;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  color: white;
}

button.cancel {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: royalblue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Modal</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="icon-item">
      <div class="icon">!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-item">
      <div class="header-item">
        <div class="header">Are you sure you want to do that?</div>
        <button class="close-button">✖</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur excepturi id soluta, numquam minima rerum doloremque eveniet aspernatur beatae commodi. Cupiditate recusandae ad repellendus quidem consectetur sequi amet aspernatur cumque!</div>
      <div>
        <button class="continue">Continue</button>
        <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



In my header-item class, I am trying to reach this desired outcome using flexbox and specifically the justify-content: space-between property. But it fails ...
I mean, the space-between value probably speaks loudly here. There is no space to rearrange the items in the container, so I think thats the problem here, that's my guess. If I am, then I would like to ask what could I do here to fix this in a smart way, not just hardcoding pixels and stuff... Is it possible? to .header-item class fill the entire parent width so its children have space to rearrange?
Thanks in advance!

By adding width:100%; on the .header-item and setting margin-left: auto; on the .close-button can make the close-button align itself in the end of the row.


body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #333;
  /* I'll give you this one for free lol */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background: white;
  width: 480px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  gap: 16px;
}

.icon-item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.info-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.header-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width:100%;
}

.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.icon {
  color: royalblue;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: lavender;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.close-button {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #888;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button.continue {
  background: royalblue;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  color: white;
}

button.cancel {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: royalblue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Modal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="icon-item">
        <div class="icon">!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="info-item">
        <div class="header-item">
          <div class="header">Are you sure you want to do that?</div>
          <button class="close-button">✖</button>
        </div>
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur excepturi id soluta, numquam minima rerum doloremque eveniet aspernatur beatae commodi. Cupiditate recusandae ad repellendus quidem consectetur sequi amet aspernatur cumque!</div>
        <div>
          <button class="continue">Continue</button>
          <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




You were very close, one line fixes it all:
.header-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; /* Forcing flex to use full width */
}

Without it your flex structure just tries to fit all the elements inside the shortest possible space.
